# zeromq installtion on mac os snow leopard

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, zeromq, pyzmq

I have installed zeromq 2.1.11 on mac os x using the steps given on 
http://www.zeromq.org/area:download

Then i installed pyzmq (python bindings )

But i get the following error :

```
import zmq

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from zmq.utils import initthreads # initialize threads
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Comment: how did you install pyzmq?  easy_install / pip / download&setup.py?  Are you using 32bit or 64bit Python?  How did you install Python?  These are all useful information when figuring out why compiled modules cannot be imported.  Specifically look at the output of `file /path/to/libzmq.dylib` and `file /path/to/initthreads.so`

Comment: thanks for reply
i did download&setup.py , passing the --zmq=   parameter
I am using 32 bit python . 
I have no understanding whats going on , i have tried for couple of days to solve .

Comment: I installed python from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2-macosx10.6.dmg

Comment: where are /path/to/libzmq.dylib and file /path/to/initthreads.so  located?

Comment: Ok something that worked finally , thx for your pointers

sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install --zmq=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/2.1.11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install --zmq=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/2.1.11/

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues (on Lion, python2.7). Even installing [the static package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq-static/2.1.7.1) didn't work for me. Ultimately, the trick was to use a slightly modified `pip` install:

```
pip install pyzmq --install-option="--zmq=bundled"
```

[[source](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq)]

Answer (score 2):

I used the pyzmq-static package on Lion 10.7.4 and it worked great: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq-static/2.1.7.1